# Regex to match adjacent characters

Tags: regex

How could one create a regex to match both permutations of two characters. For example, the regex would match `a[0-9]` and `[0-9]a`.

Comment: You'd have to hard code the permutations: `12|21`.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty in this unless you're looking for something like this [`^([12])(?!\1)[12]$`](http://regex101.com/r/qF2zL2)

Comment: Are you trying for permutations of a varable number of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having characters `X` and `Y`, you need to create a regex pattern

```
XY|YX
```

that would match such `XY` or `YX` permutations within the string.

If you want string to contain just such permutation and nothing in-front or behind, then use regex pattern

```
^XY|YX$
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using an OR:

```
^12|21$
```

You can leave off the ^ and $ if you're seeking the match anywhere in the input:

```
12|21
```